# Autenticação em serviço RESTFul

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

No exemplo abaixo, preciso passar um **par de login/senha**, pois o serviço REST exige autenticação (Basic Authentication). Então como devo passar esta informação no trecho abaixo? *(Informação adicional: a autenticação deve ser feita encodado no cabeçalho de envio)*

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://dominio:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depende da implementação do serviço REST o qual você está tentando usar. Alguns pedem a chave de API como um parâmetro opcional, outros pedem um par login/senha encodado nos cabeçalhos. Veja a documentação da API e altere a pergunta.

Comment: Prezado Rodrigo, fiz como orientado. Não é opcional, deve ser encodado no Header. Toda a documentação da API está voltada para JAVA, estou tendo dificuldades nisto. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cabeçalho da requisição `http` você pode passar um argumento chamado `Authorization`. Segundo a [documentação do http](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), este argumento por padrão espera que você informe, um `schema` de autenticação e um `token`. Você pode customizar estas informações caso a API necessite, mas por padrão o schema utilizado pelos browser são: `Basic` e o token, contém o seguinte formato: `login:senhar` em [`base64`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Você pode tentar isto:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://dominio:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", 
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", "seuUsuario", "suaSenha"))));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Felipe! Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.

Comment: Legal Santana, fico feliz em ajudar. Se possível marque como solução e mande um voteup para colaborar com o website e para outros usuários encontrarem a solução para um problema semelhante. :)

Comment: Feito! Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Após pesquisa o assunto, descobri um caminho que não só elucida como complementa o conhecimento geral sobre esse assunto. Então para quem desejar aprender mais sobre: **Segurança em Web API**, ir para esta URL[: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn376307.aspx#feedback][1]

Abraços.