# Consumir Web Service com autenticação - C#

Tags: c#, web-service

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Estou implementando uma função no meu sistema para consumir dados de um Web Service que requer autenticação (Basic Authentication), mas não consigo nenhum retorno. **A dúvida é se o modo de realizar autenticação esta correta**. Eu procurei aqui no site mesmo métodos de fazer isso e encontrei os seguintes:
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31874/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-servi%C3%A7o-restful)
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/rest)

Seguindo estes dois links eu criei o meu metodo que ficou da seguinte forma:

```
try
                {
                    var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "Usuario", "Senha");

                    var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));

                    HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();

                    var uri = new Uri("https://linkdoService");

                    cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);

                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usuario, Formatting.Indented);

                    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8);

                    var resposta = await cliente.PostAsync(uri, content);
                }
```

O código não está completo, pois eu paro a execução da aplicação para verificar o que esta me retornando e no caso a variável **resposta** fica sempre "null". Alguém poderia me dizer se este método esta correto ou estou esquecendo alguma coisa para realizar essa requisição.

Obs1: Estou usando o programa Postman para teste, ao usar a URL e as chaves de autenticação o Postman faz o retorno normal, ou seja, envio um Json e retorna um Json também.

Obs2: Eu testei também o Json que estou enviando para o Web Service, no caso o Json criado por esta linha:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usuario, Formatting.Indented);
```

funciona normalmente no Postman.

Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar, dar uma dica.

Comment: É uma requisição para um WebService ou para um HTTP Rest?

Comment: Olá Pedro, é um Web Service mesmo.

Comment: Onde está o `usuario` nesse escopo? Você comparou o json gerado no `content` com o seu do PostMan? assim como o ContentType?

Comment: Olá Leandro, o "usuario" não esta neste escopo porque é uma declaração bem grande e como testei o Json gerado por ela (na variavel json) no Postman acredito que a mesma não seja o problema. Com relação ao Json gerado no "content" eu não consegui comparar, ao parar o codigo em tempo de execução a unica informação que obtenho é que é uma variável do tipo {System.Net.Http.StringContent}.

Comment: Inclua o modelo do envio que está fazendo no no Postman, pode ser um print ofuscando os dados sensíveis mesmo.

Comment: Oi Leandro, desculpa, eu não entendi muito bem o que é para fazer. Eu preciso colocar o modelo da minha classe usuario no Postman? Obrigado.